# i can't download packages in vs for flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-packages, flutter-downloader

my country is banned and i am using vpn to acsess .
while i get a error to download packages that i need
error is like this in vs code

> Failed to download https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/1837b5be5f0f1376a1ccf383950e83a80177fb4e/sky_engine.zip. Ensure you have network connectivity and then try again.
> Exception: 403

Can anyone help me with that?

I already tried other proxies but they return the same result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/403) is the status code for "forbidden". This could be for a lot of reasons, but from what you describe it seems likely to be caused by your VPN provider.

What you can try: Access the webpage in a browser yourself or send a manual HTTP request. See if you can extract more information from the body of the response.